# Android flashlight app, can turn light on but not off

Tags: android, android-studio, flashlight

Just getting into Android programming and this is my first app. It is essentially a toggle button which turns the light on or off. The app loads fine, if I press the button it turns on fine, however if I turn it off while it is on I get "App has stopped working" message and it closes.

Can someone point where I'm going wrong? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
int flag = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            if (flag==0) {
                flag=1;
                editText.setText("ON");
                Camera camera = Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();

            }
            else {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    flag = 0;
                    editText.setText("OFF");
                    Camera camera = Camera.open();
                    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }
            }
            }



    });


}


}
```

Comment: what does log cat say?

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you get that it means you crashed.  When that happens, a stack trace and exception type will be in your logcat.  This will tell you how to debug.

However in this case I can tell you what happened.  When you call Camera.open(), you are receiving a camera object that you own until you release it.  You need to save this, and release it when your app is done with it (when it exits).  So in your off code, when you call Camera.open again it returns null, because you already own the camera and it can't give it to you again.

Actually you need to account for Camera.open returning null any time you call it-  another app may have requested the camera, in which case the OS can't give it to you and returns null.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean when you say I need to save this when I open the camera object? Also how do I release it once I'm done using it? Sorry I'm a bit new to this!

Comment: You need to store the camera object returned in a variable, rather than calling camera.open again. To release, you call camera.release

Comment: Thanks - I have added Camera camera = Camera.open(); in the global variables like int flag. This seems to work fine now, but I haven't added release() anywhere, is this bad?

Comment: Without releasing it, other apps won't be able to use the camera until yours is killed.

Comment: ok, I have added onDestroy() method and released from there, should that be sufficient?

edit: apparently this isn't what I need to do, I'm gonna think some more

Comment: You should probably release it in onPause  and open it in onResume.  Otherwise you'll continue to claim it while minimized.